# How to stop cursor in gridview text control if value not exist in that using windows form

Tags: c#

I am working on windows form application i need to stop in any cell if user does not enter any value or value is 0 after user enter any value in that cell cursor will move in next cell

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope this code help you to read a DataGridView

```
DataGridView dgv = dataGridView1;

bool breaks = false;

for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dgv.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++) {
        if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null || dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() == "0") {
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Selected = true;
            breaks = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (breaks) {
        break;
    }
}
```